# How to define the logarithm of $-1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The logarithm of a complex number $z=re^{i\theta}$ is defined (I think) as:

$$\log z=\ln |z| + i\arg z=\ln r+i\theta.$$

What is the value of $\log -1$. Following the definition, it is $\log-1=\ln1+i(-\pi)=-i\pi$. Is this correct?

Since the value $i\log i=\log i^i$ is well defined. What does $i^i$ means?

Am I missing something here?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT** My question is raised when I started trying to calculate the value of $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{i}{2(x+i)}+\dfrac{-i}{2(x-i)}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

After my calculation I found $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x=i\log-1.$$

Comment: On the complex plane you can't speak of "the" logarithm, there are different (countable many) branches of it.

Comment: $i^i = e^{(i \pi/2)i} = e^{-\pi/2}\in \Bbb{R}$. Similiarly, all other values are real!

Comment: You assume that $\log(x^y)=y\log x$ when $x,y$ are complex. This no longer works if you restrict yourself to single-valued logarithms.

Comment: If you want to compute that integral, just remember that $\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + 1} = \arctan(x)$.

Comment: @SpamIAm I know that result. I even know the value is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. I just wanted to know that if I work with complex I will get the same result or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-1=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}\implies\text{Log}(-1)=(2n+1)\pi i$$ where $n$ is any intgeer

The principal value will be $\displaystyle\log(-1)=i\pi$

---

$$i^i=(e^{\text{Log}i})^i=e^{i\cdot\text{Log}(i)}$$

As $\displaystyle i=\cos\frac\pi2+i\sin\frac\pi2=e^{i\dfrac\pi2}$ (Euler's Identity)

$\displaystyle\implies\text{Log}(i)=2m\pi i+i\frac\pi2$

Comment: The symbol `Log` with a capital `L` is often used to refer to the so-called principal branch of the logarithm. Thus `Log(−1)=(2n+1)πi` should be replaced either by `Log(−1)=πi` or by `log(−1)=(2n+1)πi`. Likewise for `Log(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct.  But a quick note.  Since many values of $\theta$ give an angle that is co-terminal with the argument of $z$, it is common to use the principal value of the argument, which is the $\theta$ such that $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$.

Regarding the second part, if $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers, 
$a^b$ is defined to be $\exp(b \log(a))$.

So $i^i$ = $\exp(i\log(i)) = \exp(i(i\pi/2)) = e^{-\pi/2}$